# Obter posição do elemento baseado em outro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tem duas 3 divs:

```
<div style="margin-top: 30px;width:50px;height:50px;"></div>

<div class="boxPrincipal">
    <div class="elementoSecundario" style="width:100px;height:80px;margin-top:10px;margin-left: 20px;">
      Conteúdo
    </div>
</div>
```

Eu precisava pegar a posição do **elementoSecundario** em relação ao **boxPrincipal**, ou seja, no caso do exemplo acima, daria mais ou menos:

**X:** 10px
**Y:** 20px;

Não quero pegar o margin-left ou margin-top, mas a posição do elemento. Repare que na primeira div tem uma outra configuração, mas **não** quero pegar a partir da primeira div e sim a partir do boxPrincipal.

Comment: [`$(element).position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) não é o que precisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do meu ponto de vista, seria `x: 20` e `y: 10`, já que há um deslocamento de `20px na horizontal` e `10px na vertical`.

de qual quer forma, você pode utilizar o método [`getBoundingClientRect`](http://caniuse.com/getboundingclientrect) para pegar a posição de ambos, então calcular a diferença usando os valores do `top` e `left`

lembrando que para a `margem` ser calculada corretamente, o elemento pai deve ter o `overflow` setado.

```js
var boxPrincipal = document.querySelector(".boxPrincipal");
var elementoSecundario = document.querySelector(".elementoSecundario");

var boundaries = {
  principal: boxPrincipal.getBoundingClientRect(),
  secundario: elementoSecundario.getBoundingClientRect()
}

console.log({
  x: boundaries.secundario.top - boundaries.principal.top,
  y: boundaries.secundario.left - boundaries.principal.left,
})
```

```css
.boxPrincipal {
  overflow: hidden;  
  background-color: teal;
}

.elementoSecundario {
  width:100px;
  height:80px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.boxQualquer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxQualquer"></div>
<div class="boxPrincipal">
    <div class="elementoSecundario">
        Conteúdo
    </div>
</div>
```

por um outro lado, se quer apenas a distancia entre o elemento filho e o pai, pode utilizar as propriedades `offsetTop` e `offsetLeft`.

Para o exemplo abaixo funcionar, o valor do `position` do elemento pai deverá ser `relative`, `absolute` ou `fixed`.

```js
var elementoSecundario = document.querySelector(".elementoSecundario");
console.log({
  x: elementoSecundario.offsetTop,
  y: elementoSecundario.offsetLeft,
})
```

```css
.boxPrincipal {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;  
  background-color: teal;
}

.elementoSecundario {
  width:100px;
  height:80px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.boxQualquer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxQualquer"></div>
<div class="boxPrincipal">
    <div class="elementoSecundario">
        Conteúdo
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var p1 = $('.elementoSecundario').offset();
var p2 = $('.elementoSecundario').position();

var X = (p1.left - p2.left);
var Y = (p1.top - p2.top)
```

`X` é o deslocamento horizontal em relação ao `.boxPrincipal`, e `Y`, o vertical.